# Is it possible to see where space is being used in a Google Account?

Tags: google-account, google-takeout

I've just prepared a Google Takeout for a user's account. I expected they would have 1-10 GB of data, but they have over 500 GB.

I checked their Google Drive which has c. 5 GB of data, so I'm not sure where the rest of it is coming from.  They don't use Gmail at all.

Without actually downloading the data is there a way I can see what data/Google products are generating the 500 GB of data?

Comment: Is this about a consumer account or about a managed account, aka Google Workspace account? Why did you not find this details in the Takeout page? Why are you asking this instead the account owner/user?

Comment: @Rubén-VolunteerModerator- this is a consumer account. I cant see that info on the takeout page (without downloading the full 500gb and exploring it on my computer, which i dont have space to do currently). Im asking this because its a question about a feature of a google account. I have updated the question slightly. please see updates.

Comment: You have access to their Google account and you have confirmed it is a consumer account so first confirm their actual used space, where it is coming from, and the storage space allowed under their plan at [Google One > Storage](https://one.google.com/storage). Then [edit] the question to include that information. Also, in Google Drive, at the end of the menu, right below **`Storage (# % Full)`**  is another line item **`## GB of ## GB used`**.  These figures include all your storage not just what is directly accessible to you in Drive. Both gOne and Drive will match.

Comment: Also, when you [edit] please clarify what the **`"c."`** means in  **`"c. 5 GB of data"`**.

Answer (score 1):

This question says "I just prepared a Google Takeout for a user's account". If this is true, you know that https://takeout.google.com/?hl=en shows a list of all the Google services that are storing user's data. Also you know that you should mark the checkbox of each of the services data to be included in the export. The details included for each service data only mentions the file formats, not the size of user's data for the corresponding service.

As Google doesn't provide in advance, and after the export is done the size of data of each service, in order to know the size and source of each part of the user's data without downloading and decompresing the export files, AFAIK, the only option is that instead of creating a single export job, create one export job for each service data. This way, the resulting file for each export job will tell correspond to one service, and the page to download the file will tell you the size of the data that come from the corresponding service.